# android Async and http client

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a custom http class in my android app to handle http post data that is sent to the server. However, I need to convert it to extend asyncTask because I need to 1, show a progress animation while the data is being fetched and 2, refresh/update the ui at the same time.

So what would be the easiest way to do this. Please note that I am already using the class throughout my app to handle httpPOST requests.

Here is the class:

```
public class Adapter_Custom_Http_Client 
{  

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Class Members">

public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds  

private static HttpClient mHttpClient;  

//</editor-fold>

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="getHttpClient">

private static HttpClient getHttpClient()
{  
    if(mHttpClient == null)
    {  
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();  
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);  
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);  
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);  
    }  
return mHttpClient;  
}
//</editor-fold>

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="executeHttpPost">

public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList postParameters) throws Exception
{  
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try
    {  
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();  
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);  
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);  
        request.setEntity(formEntity);  
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));  
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");  
        String line = "";  
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {  
            sb.append(line + NL);  
        }  
        in.close();  
        String result = sb.toString();  
        return result;  
    }
finally
    {  
        if (in != null)
        {  
            try
            {  
                in.close();  
            } catch (IOException e)
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
}
//</editor-fold>

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="executeHttpGet">

public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception
{  
BufferedReader in = null;  
    try
    {  
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();  
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();  
        request.setURI(new URI(url));  
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));  
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");  
        String line = "";  
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {  
            sb.append(line + NL);  
        }  
        in.close();  
        String result = sb.toString();  
        return result;  
    }
    finally
    {  
        if (in != null)
        {  
            try
            {  
                in.close();  
            } 
        catch (IOException e)
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
}
//</editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

follow like this:

```
 public class postmethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 //declarations what u required
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {          
 super.onPreExecute();
 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

 //do ur work here completly that will runs as background
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {       
 super.onPostExecute(result);
 } 
 }
```

Comment: How would I have to change my class in order to fit the above class you proposed. For example, In my main classes, I call the executeHttpPost method with parameters. How would I call it now ?

Comment: You could call that class or method in Void doInBackground(Void... params) method ..and instantiate the async class I have Edited....

Comment: just put that code httppost in doInBakground and call this asynctask method like this: postmethod post = new postmethod();  post.execute(); inplace of httppost

Comment: ok , I can do that, but how would I pass through the parameters needed for the executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList postParameters) ? Sorry , I'm just kind of new to asynctask.

Comment: k... no problem...i already explained declarations ... in that place u have to declare what u want

Answer (score 0):

Use this Async Class:

```
         public class Albums extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         //declarations what u required

        @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {          
           super.onPreExecute();
          ///declare ur progress view and show it

          }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //do ur http work here which is to be done in background
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {       
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //Update ur UI here...

        } 


       }
```

Any problem please ask..

EDIT:

```
     Albums alb=new Albums();
       alb.execute(null);///u can use different arguments that u need
```

Comment: How would I have to change my class in order to fit the above class you proposed. For example, In my main classes, I call the executeHttpPost method with parameters. How would I call it now ?

Answer (score 0):

Create new asynch inner class in your activity :

```
public class InnerClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = Adapter_Custom_Http_Client.executeHttpPost(url , param); 
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Please wait....");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

and execute background task using

new InnerClass().execute();

Comment: I did this, however it only executes once the post is complete. The dialog only shows for a second.